# How to access data saved in apostrophe widget?

Tags: apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I have the following widget:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    name: 'navigation',
    label:'Navigation',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'logo',
            label: 'Logo',
            type: 'singleton',
            widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
            options: {
                limit: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'menuPoints',
            label: 'Menu Points',
            type: 'area',
            options: {
                widgets: {
                    'menu': {}
                }
            }
        },
    ],
    construct: function (self, options) {
        const superLoad = self.load;
        self.load = (req, widgets, callback) => superLoad(req, widgets, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            for (const widget of widgets) {
                widget.url = req.url.substr(3);
            }

            return callback(null);
        });
    }
}
```

This is a navigation widget that allows users to populate the header with menu points using another widget, the `menu-widget`.

How do I display the data saved in multiple `'menuPoints'` on my widgets template?

I tried to iterate using `{% for menuPoint in data.widget.menuPoints %}` but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `menuPoints` is an area it is going to be a more complex object than just an array of data. I would recommend logging the object out and stepping through it to find what you want.

in your nunjucks template you can use apos.log to start logging things on the server

`apos.log(data.widget.menuPoints)`

You'll probably have to log out multiple times as you dot through the object.